# css hover element to show child, how can I keep the hover css on the parent when I mouseover the child?

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a `<ul>` with several `<li>` elements. Inside the `<li>` element there is a large `<div>` that is hidden by default. When I hover the `<li>` its background changes color as does the bottom border as well as displaying the `<div>`. This is the expected behavior. Note I am using css and not javascript for the hover effect. `.menuItem:hover .menuBody { display:block;}`. My problem is that when I hover over the now showing `<div>` its parent, the `<li>` in this case, loses it's hover style. How can I force the parent to keep the hover styling when I hover over the `<div>`? Basic html for the menu is like this. Any help or tips is of course appreciated.

```
<ul>
    <li class="menuItem">
        <a href="#">MenuItem</a>
        <div class="menuBody></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A fiddle please, with your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are asking is actually default behavior. When you hover over a child, the parent also receives the hover status, and the hover css should still be displayed. Have a look at this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jxZ6S/

We will need some more code to see what exactly is wrong. Are you sure you are applying the hover style to the parent, and not to the `a`?

Comment: I think you're correct. I applied the hover styling to the anchor tag and not the LI. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Yes this was indeed the problem. Thanks so much for your good advice!